# How to reverse the LangLat co-ordinations of geojson to LatLang so I can use it to draw polygon in leaflet js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet, maps, latitude-longitude

I am trying to draw polygons using leaflet js and I have a geojson file that has co-ordinates of different regions in langLat `[longitude,latitude]` format. But leaflet polygon requires us to use the co-ordinates in latLang `[latitude,longitude]` format. So how do I revert the array elements considering there will be different multiple dimensions of arrays for different region?

I'm using Vue-leaflet component.

```
 <l-polygon :lat-lngs="coordinates"></l-polygon>
```

I hope my question made sense. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#geojson-coordstolatlngs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Coordinate Reflection issue with Leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663604/coordinate-reflection-issue-with-leaflet)